React-Native, initializing template won't stop
Initializing templateI was trying to create a project on react-native but it has been stuck on initializing project and it won't terminate.
I have tried YouTube and chatgpt but there was no solution. I reinstalled node and git but still nothing worked.

If you use react native with expo, you can see it : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4n4CidVBj7Y&list=PLeoClvLfcvYpbemLMeuQd64TljnWq-W9I&index=13
